# how to get number of columns in an entity, like datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity, entities

I am new to entity framework.

I want to get the number of columns of an entity object just like the old Datatable technique. İs it possible ?

For example , in standart Nortwind Database , For the Customers table how can I get number of columns from Customers class derived from EntityObject;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using reflection

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
var numberCol = propertyInfos.Length;
```

instead MyClass you should use your entity class

Comment: ok thank you  you updated now it is working ?    @Serghei is it possible also to obtain the names of the columns and how?

Comment: look at this example it is in VB but is clear http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/11568-retrieve-column-names-from-table/

Comment: or look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cbaaa2e2-5f36-4b18-837c-e1f93aadb571

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by exploring the `MetadataWorkspace` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387116.aspx